# Visual Studio: Exclude a class if compiling as a dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, projects-and-solutions

I have a DLL project that I often compile as a `.exe` so that I can easily test the classes in it. One class contains a `Main()` method, which is useless when I compile it as a `.dll` file. I would like to automatically exclude this class from the project whenever I am compiling it as a class library. It seems like I must be one of the first people to run into this problem, as the almighty Google doesn't seem to have an answer for my question: How do I do this?

Comment: Create a unit test project and test your .DLL from within there

Comment: Aren't unit tests simply used for the testing of separate methods? I want to test the program as a whole.

Comment: Thing is, it isn't a program. The fundamental crux of what you have is a `.DLL` as you have said, therefore it isn't an application. Testing your methods is essentially what you are attempting to achieve anyway, isn't it?

Comment: Does the exe need to be the same project? You could just have 2 projects: the exe would reference the dll *like normal* and just add a `Main` method etc... that way you haven't changed the behavior, and you don't even need to keep changing the project configuration

Comment: @MarcGravell I guess that is what I'll do indeed. Unit test methods are not usable in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider unit testing as apose to doing this constantly. Even if unit testing isn't implemented properly and you just use it as an intermediate debugger. I would even go as far as saying do a unit test project as apose to a console application for debugging your code, in terms of getting access it will make your life a lot easier and in the future if you wish to implement some form of unit testing you can.

```
[TestMethod]
public class YourClassNameTests
{
  public T YourObject;
  [TestInitialize()]
  public void Initializer()
  {
    YourObject = new T();
  }
  [TestMethod()]
  public void YourMethodTest()
  {
    //Arrange
    YourObject.ReliantProperty = 1;
    //Act
    var objResult = YourObject.YourMethod();
    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(objResult == 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: The tests I want to do are not unit tests; they test the DLL's functionality in general. I am working with real-time acquired data, and I need the test program to display output so that I can verify whether it is correct. It is not possible to verify it programmatically.

Comment: You should then consider adding a console application project to test with, even though Luke advises against it - the idea of a separate project to perform tests sounds like the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of solutions that I can think of:

1) Use conditional compiler options. For example, only include it if it is in debug

#if DEBUG

```
public void Main() {  
// Do Stuff  
}
```

#endif

2) Make the Main method `internal`, or move it into a test project you can run. Then you either use it directly, or ensure that your test DLL can see the internal methods.

3) Move the Main method out into a completely different .exe that references the original DLL. (This is similar to option 2 without using a test framework).