# Translating C++ project from .exe to .dll?

Tags: c++

I have develped my GUI Application in Qt though Qt Creator IDE & MinGW compiler.
I plan to Open source it under the terms of GNU-LGPL.
Now since I had developed all the source code with my GUI Application in my mind, I am having difficulty in modifying the project so as to build a .dll which others can use in their applications. Here are some of my doubts:

1. Should I maintain a different sets of source files for .exe project & another for .dll project, considering that I will be maintaining my project on GitHub.
2. Should I delete all the GUI related code from the .dll project? Or it would be fine to just put bool flag's everywhere GUI is created/modified?
3. Should I delete those functions which were only used in .exe project & will never be called in .dll project? Or should I let them be as it is?

This is my first time at Application development as well as Open Source development. Since I have developed it myself, I dont have proper guidance.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate the program into two projects. Place the GUI stuff in one project which uses a dll created by your other project. That way you only need to maintain one instance of the dll's code. Having duplicate code in any way is usually a bad idea.

(Credit where credit is due: I got this idea from the third comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146486/visual-studio-exclude-a-class-if-compiling-as-a-dll). It's about C#, but the solution applies to any kind of project.)